# MySQL left join first and second results and return as one row

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to do this with MySQL. I have a table called members and a secondary table called contacts. In the table called contacts there is a field to store the id of the member that the contact is for. What I need to do is create a query to get the first and second contacts and return the results as one row.

SAMPLE DATA: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0f0c/3)

```
members:
=======
member_id | member_name
----------+------------
1         | John Doe
2         | Bob Smith
3         | Suzy Que

contacts:
=========
contact_id | member_id | contact_name
-----------+-----------+-------------
1          | 1         | Jane Doe
2          | 1         | Johnny Doe
3          | 2         | Betty Smith
```

Note: members may have up to 2 contacts but no contacts are required.

Expected Results:

```
results:
========
member_id | member_name | contact_1   | contact_2
----------+-------------+-------------+------------
1         | John Doe    | Jane Doe    | Johnny Doe
2         | Bob Smith   | Betty Smith | NULL
3         | Suzy Que    | NULL        | NULL
```

My 1st Query:

```
SELECT
  members.member_id,
  members.member_name,
  c1.contact_name AS contact_1,
  c2.contact_name AS contact_2
FROM
  members
  LEFT JOIN contacts AS c1 ON (members.member_id=c1.member_id)
  LEFT JOIN contacts AS c2 ON (members.member_id=c2.member_id)
```

Returns:

```
results:
========
member_id | member_name | contact_1   | contact_2
----------+-------------+-------------+------------
1         | John Doe    | Jane Doe    | Jane Doe
1         | John Doe    | Jane Doe    | Johnny Doe
1         | John Doe    | Johnny Doe  | Jane Doe
1         | John Doe    | Johnny Doe  | Johnny Doe
2         | Bob Smith   | Betty Smith | Betty Smith
3         | Suzy Que    | NULL        | NULL
```

Is there any way to do this without doing two different subqueries for each contact join as that seems to be inefficient.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @Dag Sondre Hansen this is an alternative solution, but I would prefer to stay two columns.

```
SELECT
  members.member_id,
  members.member_name,
  group_concat(contacts.contact_name separator ';') as contacts
FROM
  members
  LEFT JOIN contacts ON (members.member_id=contacts.member_id)
GROUP BY
  members.member_id;
```

Comment: If it is OK to return both contacts in the same column, GROUP_CONCAT may do the trick. Requires you to split the string afterwards though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  members.member_id,
  members.member_name,
  c1.contact_name AS contact_1,
  c2.contact_name as contact_2
FROM
  members
  LEFT JOIN contacts AS c1 ON (members.member_id=c1.member_id)
  LEFT JOIN contacts as c2 on (members.member_id=c2.member_id AND c1.contact_id <> c2.contact_id)
GROUP BY members.member_id
```

This did the trick for me.

NOTE: This really only works because of the data constraint of max 2 contacts per member. If this constraint changes, or if it is not enforced by your program, then the SQL here will produce different results.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more if a workaround than an actual solution, but here goes:

```
SELECT   
    members.member_id,   members.member_name,  
    GROUP_CONCAT(c1.contact_name) AS contacts 
FROM   
    members   
    LEFT JOIN contacts AS c1 ON (members.member_id=c1.member_id) 
GROUP BY    
    members.member_id;
```

Members names will pop up in the same column though.

Comment: The `AND c1.member_id <=2` is pretty much useless and will prevent functionality with larger data sets.